# BxSlider min and max slides not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I have about 10-15 slides in the .

Max slides is 4, but only 1 slide is showned. When the page loads, the slider "flashes", and show 4 slides, but after that, one slide is displayed again.

Whats wrong with the slider? Thank for helps!

You can see the problem here:[Click](http://projektar.hu/)

```
<div class="home-slider-wrapper">
              <?php
              $get_slides = mysqli_query($kapcs, "SELECT * FROM slideshow WHERE slide_status = 1 ORDER BY slide_sorrend ASC");
              if(mysqli_num_rows($get_slides) > 0 )
              {
                  echo '<ul class="bxslider">';
                    while($slide = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_slides))
                    {
                        if($slide['slide_link'] == "" )
                        {
                            echo '<li><img src="'.$host.'/images/homepage_slideshow/'.html($slide['slide_img']).'" title="'.html($slide['slide_cim']).'" /></li>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<li><a href="'.html($slide['slide_link']).'" title="'.html($slide['slide_cim']).'" target="'.html($slide['slide_link_target']).'"><img src="'.$host.'/images/homepage_slideshow/'.html($slide['slide_img']).'" title="'.html($slide['slide_cim']).'" /></a></li>';
                        }
                    }
                  echo '</ul>';
              }
              ?>
            </div>


$('.kiemelt_termekek_slider').bxSlider({
  auto: true,   
  mode: 'horizontal',
  captions: false,
  minSlides: 4
  //maxSlides: 4    
});
```

Comment: Please show the code, and if you want put it in a jsfiddle (or in your question) for people to see it in action, not an external link.

Comment: I edited the question with the code.

Comment: You have the maxSlides property commented out in the code you provided above...

Comment: If i comment it back, or remove min and max slides from the code, the problem is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is you are missing the 'slideWidth'.  Try this:

```
$('.kiemelt_termekek_slider').bxSlider({
    minSlides: 4,
    maxSlides: 4, 
    auto: true,   
    mode: 'horizontal', // This is default so you don't need it
    captions: false,
    slideWidth: 365, // This is your missing link.  Change this to the width of the slide you want and bxslider will do the appropriate calculation
  });
```

**Note:** I have marked in the code that 'mode' is already default to 'horizontal' per the documents here:

[BX Slider Options](https://bxslider.com/options/)

**EDIT:** Your code above shows this as the  selector:

```
                  echo '<ul class="bxslider">';
```

You will need to change that to 'kiemelt_termekek_slider' if that is what you are truly targeting.  Either that or change your jQuery to the following:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    minSlides: 4,
    maxSlides: 4, 
    auto: true,   
    mode: 'horizontal', // This is default so you don't need it
    captions: false,
    slideWidth: 365, // This is your missing link.  Change this to the width of the slide you want and bxslider will do the appropriate calculation
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on their examples as seen here - http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-static-number-slides

```
$('.kiemelt_termekek_slider').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 4,
  maxSlides: 4, 
  auto: true,   
  mode: 'horizontal',
  captions: false
});
```

The flickering probably has to do with how you are loading in the images.

Comment: I see the example of the dynamic number of slides, but everything is the same. I dont have no ideas whats wrong.

Comment: @TakácsZoltán If this does not work, I would guess it would be how you are loading in the images, the slider examples assume the `<li>`'s are already rendered on the page and does not account for the async you are doing there.

Comment: I have another slider on the page, in there, i only display images, not html content. That works fine, and if i delete that code from the page, and left the slider whats in my question, it still doesnt work. And i dont get any errros on the console.

Comment: @TakácsZoltán in the slider that works, are you using an async call to fetch the data like this one that doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, the images and data are coming from sql width php, not ajax. Well, the second slider works, but it dont show 4 div next to each other, only one div is displayed. 

I tried the slider with static data, but its the same. You can view the slider here. [link](http://projektar.hu)

The upper image slider works fine, the problem is with the slider under it.